# Symfony - Admin generator filters

Tags: symfony-1.4

I changed the generator on my comments module so that the results listed by default were different. I only added a 'table_method' value:

```
list:
    table_method: commentParent
```

Then I added the `commentParent` function like this:

```
public function commentParent(Doctrine_Query $q) {
    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();

    $q->where($rootAlias . '.parent_id is null or ' .  $rootAlias . '.parent_id = 0');

    return $q;
}
```

The listed results are correct but using this method, now filters won't work. In Dev mode, I can see them being correctly set in user variables, but they have no effect.

What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `addWhere` instead of `where` because it (`where`) removes all previous `where` clauses that were added.